# chrome.downloads.onCreated not working / Browser Plugin development

Tags: javascript, plugins, download, manifest.json

I'm a beginner in js and trying to code a plugin using "downloads"-API. Sadly I can't find out what's wrong. The console gives the following Error:
" main.js:6 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'onCreated') "

Manifest:

```
{ 
    "manifest_version":3,
    "version":"1.0",
    "name":"Test",
    "content_scripts":[
        {
             "matches":["<all_urls>"],
             "js":["main.js"],
             "permissions":["downloads"]
        }
    ]
}
```

main.js :

```
function handleCreated(item) {
    console.log(item); 
}
chrome.downloads.onCreated.addListener(handleCreated);
```

The error occurs directly after the DOM is loaded, so it does not even recognize that it should wait until a download has started. Any idea?

thx a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You should add chrome.downloads.onCreated(callback) in background service worker rather than content script. Your manifest.json should be following:

```
{ 
  "manifest_version":3,
  "version":"1.0",
  "name":"Test",
  "content_scripts":[
      {
           "matches":["<all_urls>"],
           "js":["main.js"]
           
      }
  ],
  "background": {
          "service_worker": "background.js"
        },
  
  "permissions":["downloads"]
}
```